# I want to use my environment.ts file URL variable in my common services, how can I read that variable?

Tags: javascript, angular

My environment  file

```
export  environment = {  
  local: true,
  title: 'Local Environment Heading',
  API URL : 'http://localhost:8090/myapp/',
  staging: false,
  production: false,
  
};
```

Common service  file

```
// here I want to read this API URL
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have an error on your enviroment file.
Check the name **API URL** it couldn't contain space on the name.
And you forgot the const on the export. (export const enviroment )

```
export const environment = {  
  local: true,
  title: 'Local Environment Heading',
  baseUrl : 'http://localhost:8090/myapp/',
  staging: false,
  production: false,
};
```

After fixing that, it's very simple to use. You just have to import the enviroment file.

For example in a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthServiceService {


  constructor() {
    const a = environment.baseUrl
   }
}
```